# How to delete scheduled task using SCHTASKS programatically?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I have created a scheduled task and then trying to deleting it using my developed java method:

```
public void deleteTask() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("schtasks.exe");
    commands.add("/DELETE");
    commands.add("/S");
    commands.add("\"ws-abacus\"");
    commands.add("/TN");
    commands.add("\"Task123\"");
    commands.add("/F");
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    Process p = builder.start();
    p.waitFor();
}
```

Running above method says `ERROR: Access is denied.`

I tried to delete using command prompt also by passing command
`schtasks /delete /S ws-abacus /TN Task123 /F` but same access denied message thrown.

Same happens with **change** scheduled task action.
I am able to delete and change from the Task Scheduler UI but not from commands or code.
Please suggest how get this action done programatically.

OS: Win7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you have not opened command prompt with elevated access. try to open the command prompt by right clicking on it and " Run as administrator". Then execute your command. it will work fine.

In case of java program, you need to run the command through elevated access mode. please do the below.

1) Create a shortcut, provide the command as cmd /c schtasks /delete /S ws-abacus /TN Task123 /F.
(right click New->shortcut. A wizard will ask for "Type the location of the item". now provide the above stated command. click next. name the shortcut as your wish. I have named it as cmd)
2) Right click the shortcut->properties and select advanced and check "run as administrator".
3) then execute the shortcut as below in you java program. I kept my shortcut named as cmd.lnk in C:

```
public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec("cmd /c start \"\" \"c:\\cmd.lnk\"");
}
```

Then everything should work fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: But in this case the task name is hard coded in the command. In my scenario the taskname is dynamic and coming through a swing UI.